# Start intent service

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I start an Intent Service this way:

```
Intent MyIntentService = new Intent(this, clsMyIntentService.class);
MyIntentService.putExtra("Command", Command1);
startService(MyIntentService );

....
Sleep and do some work
....

Intent MyIntentService = new Intent(this, clsMyIntentService.class);
MyIntentService.putExtra("Command", Command2);
startService(MyIntentService );
```

My problem is that the IntentService does not receive anything until everything is done. 
And when it starts receiving the order is wrong because Command2 is received before than Command1 (right before).

Any help with this?

Comment: It seems you are blocking UI thread, can you post more code about the "sleep and do some work"?

Comment: The code before is running in a service so it shouldn't block the UI. Anyway, the called IntentService does not depend on the UI, right?

Comment: FYI a service *runs* on the UI thread, even the IntentService, but in this case the work is dispatched to a worker thread.

Comment: Oh, no idea. I thought Services were independent of that. So, any help with this? I understand the delay then, but why is the order altered?

Comment: Probably you are creating a mess with the message queues. You need to re-design your app if you have got long operations.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your service as an **IntentService** Type, it has it's own worker thread to avoid blocking the UI and it queues the requests to start it so your commands will be executed in the correct order.

check these links for more info:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html